# invalid procedure call for an excel vba built-in function

Tags: vba, excel

The following code throws the exception *Runtime Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call*  when the value of the data found in `dataSheet.range.value` is Null

`temp = Right(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value), Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value)) - 1)`

So I fixed it with this:

```
If dataSheet.range("A" & i).value <> "" Then
        temp = Right(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value), Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value)) - 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
```

My question is adding that If statement a valid fix? It seems like something bigger might be going on that's escaping my grasp...Like shouldn't the Right() function just return nothing when the String is NULL?

Comment: First, you need to make sure that `dataSheet` is actually `Set` to something. (Also helpful to `Dim` it as a `Worksheet`)

Comment: thanks @Gaffi that stuff's done off page sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: No worries! Just thought I'd make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty cell is not null.

The problem lies in your formula: if a cell is empty or only contains spaces, `Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value))` is 0 and `Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value)) - 1` is `-1`. When you run `Right(someString, -1)` you get an error.

You should do this (it also takes care of cells that only contain spaces):

```
If Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value)) > 0 Then
    temp = Right(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value), Len(Trim(dataSheet.range("A" & i).value)) - 1)
Else
    ...
End If
```

Comment: +1 Good answer; like it when code checks the length of a string rather than the value itself if checking for blanks, nulls or empty strings.